# C++ - Passing classes to other classes. How do i know when to use friend inheritance

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have a game. The game itself is a class.

I have a couple of lines in my game that are dedicated to showing debug information:

```
RECT rct;
rct.left = 10;
rct.right = 780;
rct.top = 10;
rct.bottom = screen.GetWindowHeight() - rct.top;

std::string debugStringResult;
std::stringstream debugString;
debugString << "Mouse X: " << mouse.GetMouseX() << ",\nMouse Y: " << mouse.GetMouseY() << ",\nLeft mouse down: " << mouse.LeftMouseDown() << ",\nRight mouse down: " << mouse.RightMouseDown() << ",\nScreen width: " << screen.GetScreenWidth() << ",\nScreen height: " << screen.GetScreenHeight() << "\nSystem resolution: " << screen.GetWindowWidth() << " x " << screen.GetWindowHeight();
debugStringResult = debugString.str(); 

font.handle->DrawText( NULL, debugStringResult.c_str(), -1, &rct, 0, font.color );
```

This code is currently in my game drawing loop. Lazy isn't it :)

So I now want to declare a variable so that I do not keep re-declaring memory for my rct  and its position properties and also for the strings I am using "debugStringResult" and "debugString". Less lazy :)

I decide to create a class called Debug with the aforementioned variables and a couple of methods. I realise that I have to make a variable in my Game class to allow the creation of an instance

```
Debug debug;
```

Then I realise I have to pass my mouse, screen and gfx (for the actual draw to screen part) class references through to the debug so that the Debug class has them to output to the screen.

```
Game::Game( HWND hWnd, const MouseServer &mouseServer, const ScreenServer &screenServer )
    :   mouse( mouseServer ),
        screen( screenServer ),
        gfx( screen, hWnd ),
        font( gfx ),
        viewport( screen, gfx ),
        debug( gfx, mouse, screen )
{
```

Then it hits me. Why don't I just create a function in my Game class called Debug() and it holds that previous code with the rct and stuff in it. but then I realise, in my game class I now need to declare the variables of rct, debugString and debugResult... which to be honest, are not much to do with my game, they are to do with debugging my game... so my massively huge list of game variables just got bigger...

After all this my question is:

What would you guys do if you wanted a set of Debug related stuff that has access to all the variables ever being used in your game class.

Do you make it a friend of the game class?

Do you just bite your lip and get on with passing all the classes into the debug constructor?

Do you declare your mouse, keyboard, screen and graphics globally so you can access them everywhere? I assume not coz it's harder to debug as you need to watch the item.

Do you create a kind of "Other" class and batch all the weird funky miscellaneous stuff into it like Debug

Do you create a class that acts as a set of references to classes you end up passing through lots...? so that instead of passing through to my viewport and debug class the specific things I need, I just pass through "Reference" which is a class I would create which holds the references from my game constructor?

I just don't know what other people do and it's becoming harder to commit to my methods of doing things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your drawing code should not know about how to build a "debug string". What you want is separation of model and view.

For example, have a method be dedicated to output debug info to your screen that will be part of your rendering engine. That function then calls some kind of `GetDebugInfo()` probably from your game engine which will then pull all the necessary information from all the modules and push it with a call to a Debug object which will format the string, do whatever it wants with the information and return the appropriate debug informations to the game engine. The game engine then returns the debug string to the interface which just draws it without any interpretation at all.

I also want to add that the information you push to the Debug object should be as flexible as possible so you may want to use a hash map of properties, for example. This may not be the best way to do it (the hash map) but I encourage you to look at different ways of mapping properties to their values (what do you do if you have floating points and string values ?). This way the Debug object can look or not at properties it wants to process and it does not make the parameters heavier in the function calls. You just pass an object (or a collection, a map, whatever) and it is processed by the Debug object.

Here is a simple `system sequence diagram` to put it visually.

[image: Getting debug information]

Comment: I absolutely love the "hash" map idea. So i can have a ReferenceMap class and hold all references that I tend to pass through into my objects in that. In this case I just need to pass my ReferenceMap through into new classes that need access to these wide ranges of objects: mouse, screen, keyboard etc? This will make me much happier as there is a looser coupling between items being passed around.

Comment: This is the idea, yes. I'm not sure about the specific implementation but that is what I would recommend as a general idea for this problem yes.

Comment: Right, this Graphics separation is actually quite difficult to think out. I assume it should be difficult to separate everything out. I am realising that if i need to change to OpenGL at any time, I would have gfx references flying left right and centre and it would be hard to keep on top of, so you saying this is a wonderful clarity to me, as long as you say it should be difficult to separate this stuff out, because i am feeling the weight of the world right now lol.

Comment: Indeed it would be hard. That's why there are degrees specific to this kind of programming. I do believe that thinking really hard about those issues early in your coding will save you many headaches later.

Comment: Last question I think. Obviously from my Game constructor variables you can see I currently have (This will change) the need to have gfx for Font, screen and gfx for my viewport and mouse, screen and gfx for my debug. Does that mean that i should have a map for each specific class? Or does that start to become stupid again? the problem is i do not want to pass in parameters when they are never to be used. Would you put some kind of controller on it, like a Bitwise AND operator selection of which parameters to pass through etc?

Comment: I am not exactly sure. In this case however I am not sure why MouseServer and ScreenServer should be passed to the Game() constructor. Why can't the IO and GFX modules take care of those ?

Comment: Well my MouseServer has methods like OnMouseMove( int x, int y ) and my MouseClient has methods like GetMouseX(). these two classes are friends and it means my mouse server has scope to my game class and can be branched throughout where it's needed without having strong connections to windows msgProc. I just say that mouseServer.OnMouseMove( x, y ) and then if I change to another platform like crApple, I can still use the same functions. Does that sound all okay to you? I'm brand new to C++, i'm just learning from others examples (Chili DirectX Tutorial, youtube)

Comment: My D3DGraphics class which creates directX surfaces etc should house all rendering and i need to sort that out, from your help, i now see that this is a mess and makes such decoupling of mouse and screen completely pointless when the most important part of my project is so tightly coupled with DirectX... dOH! P.S thank you for putting so much time into this!